# Is there any notation for the undecimal system?

Tags: notation, number-systems

Decimal is
0
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9
10;11;...
But undecimal
0
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;?
?0;?1

TWas this system used by an ancient civilisation ?

(I don't know what to tag)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecimal tells us, that it was acutally used

Comment: I changed the tag from [tag:logic] to [tag:notation] and [tag:number-systems]

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make up your own notation.  Or as there is only one symbol to add we can call it $TEN$.

so the numbers are:

$1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;TEN$

$10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;1TEN$

$20;21.......$

Although any modern mathematician doing this would probably use $A$.

I'm more interested in how the Maori used it practically.  I imaging they counted to ten and probably had a place holder that the gave as an actually number *and* a transition to the next set of ten number (and then a *second* place holder).... Maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Hexadecimal traditionally uses 'digits' 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F; it looks reasonable to use 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A for undecimal.

Comment: I intuitively would use X instead of A, i.e. the Latin character for ten. I would start with A, B, ... at base twelve,  however. It's just that an A without a B feels ugly, but that's of course debatable...